# Control IO using PLC program

Tags: plc, twincat

Is it possible to disable IO devices on Twincat 2 using the PLC program? EtherCAT connects all IO devices.

I am trying to disable an IO device using a digital input to avoid Hardware Configuration faults when the IO device is disconnected from the EtherCAT.

Comment: I don't know TwinCAT in depth, but in Codesys 2.3, which is similar, you achieve this by setting the device settings on the EtherCAT network to "Simulation", unfortunately this requires loading the program again, it is not available as a programmable variable.

Answer (score 0):

With the hot-connect feature you can create optional IO devices in the EtherCat bus.
Making it possible to add/remove hardware on the fly without the need to reconfigure. See [InfoSys](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/ethercatsystem/2469078667.html).

With the experience I have with it, it was possible to add hardware anywhere in the bus as long as the device could be recognized by an unique Id. I'm not sure if it works for single IO-cards, but it definitely works for IO groups with an EtherCat coupler or for stand-alone EtherCat devices. It's possible you need an extra EtherCat coupler for the optional card to have it separated and make it work.